# SQLite select numbers of album

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want select the uniques artist with the numbers of albums.

In the MusicLibrary table, the individual songs are saved. (title, artist, album ...)

I have tried:

```
SELECT distinct artist, album, Count(*) from MusicLibrary group by artist order by artist
```

but I get the number of songs.

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me

Comment: Remove `distinct` and `album` from the `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you save every song in that table you need to use `distinct`  in your count to only count unique albums and not the number of songs for every artist

```
SELECT artist, Count(distinct album) as albums
from MusicLibrary 
group by artist 
order by artist
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that works. I dont know that i can use distinct in Count

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT artist, Count(album)
from MusicLibrary
group by artist
order by artist
```